# How is the changing of one list affecting a completely different list?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, observablecollection

I have the following code:

```
jobsToShiftUp.AddRange(PresentationManager.Instance.ScheduleViewSource.Where(o => o.Resources.First().ResourceName == criticalJob.Resources.First().ResourceName && ((o.Start >= criticalJob.Start) || (o.Start < criticalJob.Start && o.End > criticalJob.Start)) && !o.JobGuid.Equals(((Job)state.DraggedAppointments.First()).JobGuid) && GetWeekNumber(o.Start) == GetWeekNumber(criticalJob.Start)));
jobsToShiftUp = jobsToShiftUp.OrderBy(o => o.Start).ToList();
TimeSpan timeToShift = criticalJob.End - jobsToShiftUp.First().Start;

foreach (Job job in jobsToShiftUp)
{
    if (jobsToShiftUp.IndexOf(job) == 0)
    {
        ((ObservableCollection<Job>)state.DestinationAppointmentsSource).Single(o => o.JobGuid.Equals(job.JobGuid)).Start += timeToShift;
        ((ObservableCollection<Job>)state.DestinationAppointmentsSource).Single(o => o.JobGuid.Equals(job.JobGuid)).End += timeToShift;
```

......

The last two lines (increasing the start and end properties of the jobs) affects both the state.destinationappointmentssource list AND the jobsToShiftUp list (i.e. it affects the job object currently being referenced in the foreach loop). I can't think why it would affect the jobsToShiftUp list at all!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both object have same reference.

So `jobsToShiftUp` collection and `state.DestinationAppointmentsSource` might both have some same reference and updating the one reflecting in another.

You can use cloning (deep copy) to avoid this .

Answer (score 3):

Since both list contain the same instances of objects.
Like:

```
Job job = new Job();
List<Job> list1 = new List<Job>{job};
List<Job> list2 = new List<Job>{job};
```

`list[0].Start+=10` will add 10 to `job` which is also referenced by `list2`